# How do I write to a file in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, file-writing

I can't seem to find this question yet, but what is the simplest, most-idiomatic way of opening/creating a file, writing to it, and then closing it? Looking at the [kotlin.io](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/index.html) reference and the Java documentation I managed to get this:

```
fun write() {
    val writer = PrintWriter("file.txt")  // java.io.PrintWriter

    for ((member, originalInput) in history) {  // history: Map<Member, String>
        writer.append("$member, $originalInput\n")
    }

    writer.close()
}
```

This works, but I was wondering if there was a "proper" Kotlin way of doing this?

Comment: I added more variations in a new answer for fun, to give you more ideas of things you can do.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

A bit more idiomatic.  For PrintWriter, this example:

```kotlin
File("somefile.txt").printWriter().use { out ->
    history.forEach {
        out.println("${it.key}, ${it.value}")
    }
}
```

The `for` loop, or `forEach` depends on your style.  No reason to use `append(x)` since that is basically `write(x.toString())` and you already give it a string.  And `println(x)` basically does `write(x)` after converting a `null` to `"null"`.  And `println()` does the correct line ending.

If you are using `data` classes of Kotlin, they can already be output because they have a nice `toString()` method already.

Also, in this case if you wanted to use `BufferedWriter` it would produce the same results:

```kotlin
File("somefile.txt").bufferedWriter().use { out ->
    history.forEach {
        out.write("${it.key}, ${it.value}\n")
    }
}
```

Also you can use `out.newLine()` instead of `\n` if you want it to be correct for the current operating system in which it is running.  And if you were doing that all the time, you would likely create an extension function:

```kotlin
fun BufferedWriter.writeLn(line: String) {
    this.write(line)
    this.newLine()
}
```

And then use that instead:

```kotlin
File("somefile.txt").bufferedWriter().use { out ->
    history.forEach {
        out.writeLn("${it.key}, ${it.value}")
    }
}
```

And that's how Kotlin rolls.  Change things in API's to make them how you want them to be.

Wildly different flavours for this are in another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35462184/3679676

Comment: it may an other possible solution: File(fileName).writeText(Iterable<Any>.joinToString(), Charsets.UTF_8)

Comment: @IstvanNagy depending on the size of the iterable and if you want to materialize the full string before writing.  I'll add it to the alternative answer, it is nice and short!

Comment: For reference, since I spent about an hour trying to figure this out, if you're going to be opening and closing a file multiple times for appending text, use `FileWriter("output.txt", true).use {` for the 1st line. (Otherwise, the textfile is cleared each time you open it)

Comment: Does that imply that the `printWriter` is not using any buffering? Which would make me wonder _why_? It feels wrong having to decide between either buffering or the convenience of having a line-writing function out-of-the-box.

Comment: No @bluenote10 that is not implied, that was just another example of how to use a different interface to write.

Answer (score 39):

**Other fun variations** so you can see the power of Kotlin:

A quick version by creating the string to write all at once:

```kotlin
File("somefile.txt").writeText(history.entries.joinToString("\n") { "${it.key}, ${it.value}" })
// or just use the toString() method without transform:
File("somefile.txt").writeText(x.entries.joinToString("\n"))
```

Or assuming you might do other functional things like filter lines or take only the first 100, etc. You could go this route:

```kotlin
File("somefile.txt").printWriter().use { out ->
    history.map { "${it.key}, ${it.value}" }
           .filter { ... }
           .take(100)
           .forEach { out.println(it) }
}
```

**Or given an `Iterable`, allow writing it to a file** using a transform to a string, by creating extension functions (similar to `writeText()` version above, but streams the content instead of materializing a big string first):

```kotlin
fun <T: Any> Iterable<T>.toFile(output: File, transform: (T)->String = {it.toString()}) {
    output.bufferedWriter().use { out ->
        this.map(transform).forEach { out.write(it); out.newLine() }
    }
}

fun <T: Any> Iterable<T>.toFile(outputFilename: String, transform: (T)->String = {it.toString()}) {
    this.toFile(File(outputFilename), transform)
}
```

used as any of these:

```kotlin
history.entries.toFile(File("somefile.txt")) {  "${it.key}, ${it.value}" }

history.entries.toFile("somefile.txt") {  "${it.key}, ${it.value}" }
```

or use default toString() on each item:

```kotlin
history.entries.toFile(File("somefile.txt")) 

history.entries.toFile("somefile.txt")
```

**Or given a `File`, allow filling it from an `Iterable`**, by creating this extension function:

```kotlin
fun <T: Any> File.fillWith(things: Iterable<T>, transform: (T)->String = {it.toString()}) {
    this.bufferedWriter().use { out ->
        things.map(transform).forEach { out.write(it); out.newLine() }
    }
}
```

with usage of:

```kotlin
File("somefile.txt").fillWith(history.entries) { "${it.key}, ${it.value}" }
```

or use default toString() on each item:

```kotlin
File("somefile.txt").fillWith(history.entries)
```

which if you had the other `toFile` extension already, you could rewrite having one extension call the other:

```kotlin
fun <T: Any> File.fillWith(things: Iterable<T>, transform: (T)->String = {it.toString()}) {
    things.toFile(this, transform)
}
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/write-text.html

Answer (score 5):

It mostly looks ok to me. The only thing different I would do is use the "[use](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/io/ReadWrite.kt)" extension defined in ReadWrite to auto close the writer.

```
PrintWriter("file.txt").use {
  for ((member, originalInput) in history) {  // history: Map<Member, String>
    it.append("$member, $originalInput\n")
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

At the very minimum, you could use:

`FileWriter(filename).use { it.write(text) }`

[FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) is a convenience class for writing character files (provided by Java, and hence available in Kotlin). It extends Closeable, and hence can be used by Kotlin's ".use" extension method.

The [.use](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) extension method automatically closes the calling object once the block exits, thus providing an idiomatic way to close the file after it's written.

Answer (score 2):

```
try{
      val fileWriter = FileWriter("test.txt", true)
      fileWriter.write(string+ "\n")
      fileWriter.close()
    } catch (exception: Exception){
        println(exception.message)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Some Kotlin magic allows to omit referencing the stream on each read or write call:

```
fun <T : Closeable, R> T.useWith(block: T.() -> R): R = use { with(it, block) }

File("a.in").bufferedReader().useWith {
    File("a.out").printWriter().useWith {
        val (a, b) = readLine()!!.split(' ').map(String::toInt)
        println(a + b)
    }
}

Scanner(File("b.in")).useWith {
    PrintWriter("b.out").useWith {
        val a = nextInt()
        val b = nextInt()
        println(a + b)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example as easy

```
val path = context!!.filesDir.absolutePath // => /data/user/0/com.example.test/files
File("$path/filename.txt").writeText("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

File(requireContext().filesDir, "TodayTaskListChange.txt").writeText("write your test here...")