# How to write to text file - after reading from input?

Tags: file, kotlin

Alternative title: how does one "nicely" "update" the contents of text files with Kotlin?

I have seen [how do i write to a file in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444264/how-do-i-write-to-a-file-in-kotlin/35445704).

Basically, the suggested solution there is based on creating a File object, to then write to it: `File("somefile.txt").printWriter().use ...`

But well: I already have code like this:

```
File(fname).bufferedReader().lineSequence().flatMap { transform(it) }
```

where `transform()` is my own method that either returns the original line, or some updates lines when some specific match matched. (its signature is `transform(line : String) : Sequence<String>`)

Sure: I could assign the result of `flatMap()` to some temporary variable, to then use that with `printWriter().use`.

But is there a nice, canonical way that works **without** a temporary variable?

Comment: Just use it directly. Nothing requires the declaration of a variable to use it elsewhere. `[...].printWriter().use { File(fname).bufferedReader().lineSequence().flatMap { transform(it) } }`

Comment: @Zoe Feel free to put that into an answer. Would be easier to read, and earn you an upvote + accept.

Comment: joinToString() and File.writeText?

Comment: The code i posted in the comment is wrong. The return type doesn't match, and it doesn't actually write anything. Anyways, what does transform return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your reading code (`File().bufferedReader().lineSequence()`) can already be simplified to:

```
File(fname).useLines {
  it.flatMap(::transform)
}
```

Now regarding writing without putting it in an intermediate variable...

```
File("writeTo").bufferedWriter().use { writer ->
  File("readFrom").useLines { lines ->
    lines.flatMap(::transform)
         .forEach { 
           writer.appendln(it)
         }
  }
}
```

But I am not yet really convinced about it... I don't really like it ;-)
I rather like something like:

```
File("readFrom").useLines {
   ..
}.writeTo("writeTo")
```

but that is not going to work as long as I use `useLines` ;-)

But here is something similar:

```
File("readFrom").useLines {
  it.flatMap(::transform)
    .writeTo(File("writeTo"))
}
```

But this requires the following extension function then:

```
fun Sequence<String>.writeTo(file: File) {
  file.bufferedWriter().use { writer -> forEach { writer.appendln(it) } }
}
```

On the other hand... I always wanted to have a sequence.toFile-writer ;-) adapted it already to use a delimiter as parameter...