# How do I write to a file in Kotlin? Nothing I've found works

Tags: kotlin, file-io

I'm having trouble with writing to a file. Here is my code:

```
File("test.txt").printWriter().use { out ->
            out.println("First line")
            out.println("Second line")
```

I've looked that the answers at [How do I write to a file in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444264/how-do-i-write-to-a-file-in-kotlin) but they don't work; gradle builds and runs but `test.txt` stays empty. I've also checked the Kotlin documentation but I can't find anything.

Thanks!

Edit: If I put the full path of the file then it works.

Comment: This works fine for me, what's your root directory, can you find it using `println(File("test.txt").path)`?

Comment: Regarding your edit, writing to `File("test.txt")` will write to a file located at `<working-directory>/test.txt` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). Is that the file you were looking at? Is that the same path used when you manually enter the absolute path?